# Enclose with an ul al li groups (there might be several ones)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to generate a list block with a given string. I want to convert all lines that begin with a *, to a list. For example:

```
Text...
* One
* Two
Other text.
```

I have done it with a php regexp.

```
$source=preg_replace("/^\*([^\n]*)/m","<li>$1</li>",$source);
```

How can I get it to enclose all the created li groups between "ul" tags?. It might be blocks with three "li" lines, with ten "li" lines, and so on... I tried to search for all parents like: 
**"NOT < /li > + < li > + (WHATEVER) + < /li > + (NOT < li >)"**, but this is impossible.

Comment: Are you also converting other text syntaxes to HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to match consecutive pairs of `<li>...</li>` elements and wrap those in `<ul>`:

```
preg_replace('#((?:<li>.*?</li>\s*)+)#', '<ul>\1</ul>', $source);
```

The inner `(?: ... )` group matches one `<li> ... </li>`, optionally followed by white space; this whole match then needs to exist at least once.

Btw, the `?:` doesn't match anything, it's used to indicate that the surrounding group should not be allocated a memory slot for back references.

By using the non-greedy `.*?` this can match separate sections of `<li>`'s, e.g.

```
Text...
* One
* Two
Other text.
* Three
* Four
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot this was a very interesting solution for it (just needed to escape the li closing slash). I wanted to know... why does the group need to start with an "?:"?

Comment: @Kenedy updated my answer to explain what `?:` does .. it doesn't match anything in short :) and you don't need to escape the closing slash, because I'm using `#` as the expression enclosure.

Comment: Ups... sorry for my wrong correction. The thing is that I replaced it by the slashes expression enclosure (in order to have the same for all) and didn't know the difference between both ones. Thank you again for the explanation, it is working perfect now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but this:
`$source = preg_replace('/\* ([^\r\n]+)/', '<li>$1</li>', $source);`

Will transform:

```
* Test1
* Test2
* Test3
* Test4
```

Into:

```
<li>Test1</li>
<li>Test2</li>
<li>Test3</li>
<li>Test4</li>
```

Edit:
`$source = preg_replace('<li>(.+)</li>', '<ul><li>$1</li></ul>', preg_replace('/\* ([^\r\n]+)/', '<li>$1</li>', $source));`

... will enclose or the `<li>`s in an `<ul>`

Comment: I think in that case it should have a multiline modifier, and it is quite similar to what I have. I need that, once applied this regular expression, enclose all "li" groups into the open and close ul tags. Thank you anyway =)